# `div input[type='checkbox']:lt(2)` only selecting first row

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I want to cause an alert when the user clicks on either of the first two `<input>`s in each row, but my current code is only working for the first row. How can I fix my selector to work for the rest of the rows?

HTML:

```
<div>
    <input type='checkbox' />
    <input type='checkbox' />
    <input type='checkbox' />
</div>
<div>
    <input type='checkbox' />
    <input type='checkbox' />
    <input type='checkbox' />
</div>
<div>
    <input type='checkbox' />
    <input type='checkbox' />
    <input type='checkbox' />
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
 $("body").on("click", "div input[type='checkbox']:lt(2)", function() {
    alert("x");
});
```

I have a JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/yxmeA/393/

Comment: work only for first div

Comment: The `:lt` `[...]Select all elements at an index less than index within the matched set.`, as of that the callback will be called for the first two elements that will be found by the selector `div input[type='checkbox']`

Comment: It works for the first two checkboxes at the top for me. Do you only want it to work for the first two on the left?

Comment: @t.niese is right.  You may want to rethink what you are selecting and binding the listener to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a selector like `:nth-child(-n+2)`:

```
$("body").on("click", "div input[type='checkbox']:nth-child(-n+2)", function() {
    alert("x");
});
```

This is because your `:lt(2)` selector was selecting all of the inputs, and then filtering to only the first 2. Here, we check if it's the first 2 children of its parent.

```js
$("body").on("click", "div input[type='checkbox']:nth-child(-n+2)", function() {
    alert("x");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <input type='checkbox' />
    <input type='checkbox' />
    <input type='checkbox' />
</div>
<div>
    <input type='checkbox' />
    <input type='checkbox' />
    <input type='checkbox' />
</div>
<div>
    <input type='checkbox' />
    <input type='checkbox' />
    <input type='checkbox' />
</div>
```

You can see [nthmaster.com](http://nthmaster.com/#example_two) for more information on this powerful selector.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a good idea to number the elements themselves, since it seems your program logic is dependent on the element position. CSS selectors are very powerful, but there might be an easier solution. For example:

HTML:

```
<div data-y="0">
    <input type='checkbox' data-x="0"/>
    <input type='checkbox' data-x="1" />
    <input type='checkbox' data-x="2" />
</div>
<div data-y="1">
    <input type='checkbox' data-x="0" />
    <input type='checkbox' data-x="1" />
    <input type='checkbox' data-x="2" />
</div>
<div data-y="1">
    <input type='checkbox' data-x="0" />
    <input type='checkbox' data-x="1" />
    <input type='checkbox' data-x="2" />
</div>
```

JS

```
$("div > input[type='checkbox']").on("click", function() {
    alert($(this).data('x') + ', ' + $(this).parent().data('y'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hhqcwepf/

Answer (score 0):

You can use extremely simple selectors to do this. Select all `<input>` elements that aren't prepended by two others.

```js
$('div input:not(input+input+input)').click(function() {
  alert("x");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <input type='checkbox' />
    <input type='checkbox' />
    <input type='checkbox' />
</div>
<div>
    <input type='checkbox' />
    <input type='checkbox' />
    <input type='checkbox' />
</div>
<div>
    <input type='checkbox' />
    <input type='checkbox' />
    <input type='checkbox' />
</div>
```